# WP Job Manager Feature jobs from [job_dashboard] page

Tags: plugins

I'm using [WP Job Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) Plugin.

I want to make a link on the [job_dashboard] page which allow users to make featured their jobs.

I'm added this code to job-dashboard.php:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . update_post_meta( $job->ID, '_featured', 1 ) . '">Featured</a></li>';
```

But this is make featured all of my jobs not the one where I clicked the link.

How can I do that make featured the one which I clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you're doing it wrong.

#### Long answer

`update_post_meta` actually updates the field, so whenever your code runs, the value of `_featured` is updated to `1`. No clicking necessary, you're actually telling it to update the value right then and there.

What you should do is have your link point to a page that can handle the request when the link is clicked:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . add_query_arg( 'set_featured_id', $job->ID ) . '">Featured</a>';
```

Then, process that information:

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $job_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'set_featured_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

    if ( null === $job_id ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta( $job_id, '_featured', 1 );
});
```

The above solution is really insecure, however. You should probably look at functions to "gate" whether the user can do this - such as `current_user_can` - you could also look into doing this as part of a form submission, which would allow you to leverage `wp_nonce_field` as well for some added security.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help! :) yeah, I'm newbie in wordpress. But I add some security for this. Thanks again.

Comment: I need your help again if you dont' mind and you know how to do this. So I want to schedule a wp cron job after I clicked the Featured link then after 7 days sets the job "unfeatured" _featured 0 or something like this. Can you help me in this?

Comment: You may need to ask a new question with more details of what you're trying to do.